# Socket.io Page Loading Forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, pug

Note - I'm using Pug to render my pages.

My page, when including the `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")`, does not stop loading.

Here's the relevant content from my `app.js`.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

All packages are installed correctly.

In my head tag:

```
  script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
  script.
    var socket = io();
```

Yet, my page does not stop loading. What have I done wrong here?

Update:

app.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const AppError = require('./utils/appError');
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errorController');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const viewRouter = require('./routes/viewRoutes');
const projectRouter = require('./routes/projectRoutes');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

//MIDDLEWARES
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requestTime = new Date().toISOString();
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'overview'));
})

//ROUTES
app.use('/', viewRouter);
app.use('/api/1/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/1/projects', projectRouter)

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Can't find ${req.originalUrl}.`, 404));
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

server.js (run by node)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// mongoose.set('debug',true);
dotenv.config({path: './config.env'})
const app = require('./app');

const DB = process.env.DB.replace('<PASSWORD>', process.env.DBPASS);

mongoose.connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(con => {console.log(' Connected.')})


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(` Running on ${port}.`)
});

const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('greeting', msg => {
      console.log(msg);
  })
});

http.listen(80);
```

Comment: Are you loading your web page from the exact same server whose code you show here?

Comment: yes @jfriend00.

Comment: Well, go to the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see what exact resource from your page is not loading.  You may also discover some other helpful messages or errors.

Comment: No errors in Network tab, or Console.

Comment: Well, if your page hasn't finished loading, then some request in the network tab must not be complete yet.  Which one is it?

Comment: `socket.io.js` is pending. Everything else has loaded.

Comment: I'd say reinstall the server-side socket.io library.  Something is apparently wrong with it.

Comment: okay, I'll try that

Comment: still doesn't seem to be working. Even when directing the script link to the node_modules folder it doesn't load.

Comment: You can't point the client to the `node_modules` folder unless you specifically added a route for some other path.  The loading of socket.io.js from your server only works because the socket.io server code adds a route to your Express server explicitly for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  Express servers don't serve any files by default so pointing the client to a particular path in your server file system won't do anything useful unless the server has a route for that specific path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've shown your code, this part is wrong:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(` Running on ${port}.`)
});

const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

You are creating two separate servers there and binding socket.io to the one that isn't running.  Change that above code to this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(` Running on ${port}.`)
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

---

**Earlier attempt to help before OP had shown their actual code.**

My guess is that something is messed up in your environment or something is wedged in your OS or something is blocking some requests.  To rule things in or out, I would suggest you try this simple app which works just fine for me:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const path = require('path');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "temp.html"));
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on("greeting", msg => {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

server.listen(80);
```

and the HTML file `temp.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="myButton">Press Me</button>

<script>
const socket = io();
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
    socket.emit("greeting", "hi from client");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You put these two files in the same project and you have the server-side socket.io library installed in that project (it should be in node_modules per a normal installation).

Start the server with `node app.js` in a way that has a server console that you can see output from.  Then, from a browser on the same computer, go to `http://localhost`.  It should load a web page with a single button on it.  Press that button.  You should see a message in the server console that says `hi from client` each time you press that button.

If this is working, then we would need to see all your project code to see what's wrong with your actual project.

If this isn't working, then we need to know what errors you get.  You can try moving this project to a different port in case you have something blocking some things on a particular port.  You can reboot your computer in case something in the networking or file system is wedged.

Comment: Hello, thanks, however it does not seem to work yet. I've actually given both my javascript files to maybe help to solve it. Do you have any other ideas after reading them?

Comment: @Matt - See what I added to the start of my answer.  You were creating two separate http servers and binding socket.io to the one that wasn't running.